# bcrypt with nodejs compare always false

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

i always get a false compare with this line of block for unknown reason even when the user password mathes the hashed password i have in my DB. please help.

```
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password , function(error, result) {
          console.log(result==true);
          if (result === true) {
            return callback(null, user);
          } else {
            return callback();
          }
        })
      });
}
// hash password before saving to database
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  var user = this;
  bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, function(err, hash) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    user.password = hash;
    next();
  })
});
```

full project and code can be found here:
https://github.com/eladnm/Trinity-Management-System-

Comment: What is `password` on the first line?

Comment: the password  i have in my DB.

Comment: What we can see of your code looks ok, as you sure that the hashed password is actually being saved to the db? Maybe do a console.log of both of them before invoking `bcrypt.compare`

Comment: This line `user.password = hash`. Are you sure you don't need a call to some kind of `save` function?

Comment: when console.log both of them i get the password i entered and the hashed password i have in my DB. so they are the same. one as typed and one after hash in my DB

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, `result === true` returns false as result might not be an actual true value. It could be a truthly value and which when compared with `==` returns true. (From bcrypt's [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt))

You could simply write:

```
if (err) {
  return callback(err);
}
if (result) {
  return callback(null, user);
} 
return callback();
```